# java arraylist return value situation

Tags: java

I'm trying to use an arraylist to store integer values, and execute as you can see below, i'm brand new to arraylists, so sorry in advance guys! :(

```
package server.model.content;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import server.model.players.Client;

public class RandomRewards 
{
    private static ArrayList<Integer> items = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void addItems(Client c)
    {
        c.getItems().addItem(items.get(arrayItems()), 1);
    }

    private static int arrayItems()
    {
// the items I want to store inside of the arraylist, and then call above
        items.add(4151);
        items.add(4720);
        return items.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use an arraylist to store integer values, and execute as you can see in additems

Comment: In the example above, what exactly are you trying to add to the Client c?  All the items in the list (4151, 4720)?

Comment: Please be specific about the question you are asking and at least include the necessary code like we are unable to figure out what your "getItems()" method going to do kinda stuff. Please rephrase your question so we can help you easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try declaring a static int to store the size of the ArrayList items.

```
private static int = z;
```

Then, in your addItems method you should first set z to arrayItems()

```
z = arrayItems();
```

This will store the size of the ArrayList in z.  Now, you need to store the items.

```
static void addItems(Client c) {
  for(int i = 0; i < z; i++)  {
    c.getItems().addItem(items.get(i), 1);  //not sure what your addItem() parameters are, nor the significance of the getItems() so I retained the format.
  }
}
```

May I also suggest that you use more descriptive variables.  It may make it easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for this, if I wanted to pick a random item from the arraylist how would I use Random class in this situation. Thank you so much, I dont really use this site so i'm not as great in posting as I should be

Comment: so, instead of adding the full ArrayList, (4151, 4720) you want to add one at random?

Comment: Yes sir, so the user would get whatever is randomly picked.

Comment: use random to select a number from 0 to ArrayList.size()

Comment: so something like this ? " return r.nextInt((items.size())); "

It only prints out the first item in the list

Comment: are you adding that in the arrayItems() method?  It should go into a new method addItem(Client c).

I would do `int num = (int) (Math.random() * items.size());`

Comment: If you need any more help on other topics you should probably open a new question